# Modifying T4 code templates for ASP.NET MVC to get rid of full namespace reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4, code-templates

We're using (**there is need to tell where the files are, thanks**) custom T4 code templates on creating a view or controller. Default implementation makes this kind first row.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ProjectNameHere.ViewModels.ViewModelClass>" %>
```

We have already ViewModel and MVC namespace defined in the Web.config, so I would like code template to generate this.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="ViewPage<ViewModelClass>" %>
```

Any suggestions how modify the default templates to get that kind of results? Which of the template lines actually generate these?

**More information**

I know where the files are and modifications has been made. Problem is that in the template they're using this

```
string mvcViewDataTypeGenericString = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mvcHost.ViewDataTypeName)) ? "<" + mvcHost.ViewDataTypeName + ">" : String.Empty;
```

It seems that ViewDataTypeName contains full namespace reference. I would like get just name of the class (in this case ViewModel class name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the templates here:

*\Microsoft Visual Studio \Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 2\CodeTemplates*

There you can edit the generated code for each template, the template lines vary for each template so i cannot tell you, but you will spot them immidiately.

**EDIT**

The source for Web.Extensions is not available, but you can make use of relector and reflect on 
*\Microsoft Visual Studio \Common7\IDE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.dll* assembly to see what "mvcHost" gives you :)

You will then notice a ViewDataType property which is a "Type", and you should then be able to create some logic around it to get the class name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that there isn't more cleaner way to do it than manipulating the namespace string.